# C# MVC System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error, I believe that it is because I have one two many `Html.RenderAction();` on my home page. On top of a few `@Html.Partial()` My site is fine if I remove the last one I put in. Which is bringing up a list of Operating hours from a table. I have 2 on the footer one to show recent posts and the hours. The Footer is on a Partial page. In total there are `Login Partial`, `Cart Summary -- RenderAction`, and `Footer Partial` on the main Layout page plus of course `RenderBody()`. The Index page has 2 partials on it so far and was planning on using more. All of these have models to tables attached to them from tables. I get the error on the login Partial and sometimes on the blog posts. If I comment out the one I just made it works fine. And navigating to the page itself works with no errors. At first I had it as a partial page in the shared folder and it just doesn't show up. I have done all of these,

```
  public ActionResult _Hours()
    {
        var hrs = db.OperatingHours.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder).ToList();

        return PartialView(hrs);
    }

  public ActionResult Hours()
    {
        var hrs = db.OperatingHours.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder).ToList();

        return View(hrs);
    }
```

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Stackoverflow exceptions are almost always due an infinite loop -- looking at the stacktrace should show a pattern of repeating calls my assumption is correct.

Comment: "I believe that it is because I have one two many Html.RenderAction(); on my home page." .. no, it is because of the *way* you wrote the code.  The debugger is your friend.  Step through ALL code you write.  @DavidTansey is certainly correct.

Comment: @DavidTansey absolutely correct.. My view has Foreach and a couple of if statements inside of it. I changed it from the 2 if's to a If else and it is now working. I guess I really didn't need 2 bools Just the one. Thanks for your help.. I will put a solution in the bottom to finalize the answer..

Answer (score 0):

The issue was as David mentioned above in the comments, I had an infinite loop in my view code. Below is how it originally was written.

```
    <ul class="list-border">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li class="clearfix">
            @if (item.SelOpen == true)
            {
                <span>@if (item.ShowSelect == true)
                {<text>Select</text>} @item.Day :  </span>
                <div class="value pull-right flip"> @item.OpenTime @if (item.ShowBreak == true)
                {<text>-</text> @item.BreakTime} - @item.CloseTime </div>
            }
            @if (item.SelClosed == true)
            {
                <span> @item.Day :  </span>
                <div class="value pull-right flip"> Closed </div>
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Below is the code that it was changed to for it to work.

```
    <ul class="list-border">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li class="clearfix">
            @if (item.SelOpen == true)
            {
                <span>@if (item.ShowSelect == true)
                {<text>Select</text>} @item.Day :  </span>
                <div class="value pull-right flip"> @item.OpenTime @if (item.ShowBreak == true)
                {<text>-</text> @item.BreakTime} - @item.CloseTime </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <span> @item.Day :  </span>
                <div class="value pull-right flip"> Closed </div>
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

I normally code the above way with `if(){ }else{}. And I guess I have done it the other way as well, but not in a foreach loop.. Lesson learned.